# Best solution to draw lines and shapes on an image rendered

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I want to ask a question in regards to this thing I am trying to accomplish. I want render an image and have onclicks on the image to be able to create shapes around the image. Is using the canvas API the most solution for this?

This is a general question since I am in the planning stage of a project.

Answer (score 0):

draw your image on canvas then edit canvas as you desire

Comment: thanks very much. I am thinking about creating this canvas into a reusable component to edit other images would do you recommend using native Canvas Api or a framework like hmm lets say p5.js

Comment: it really depends on type of work you want to do if you have so much edits I recommend using a frame work